# Deezer JS SDK player HTML5 fallback not working on iOS / Android

Tags: deezer

http://dadabik.org/deezer_test/deezer_test.html

I've build something similar, with the exception that I only play the track for less than 30 seconds. This way Deezer player works for not logged in users with Desktop browsers flawlessly. It just doesn't work on mobile devices with the HTML5 fallback.

But, I can't get the example working on iOS 7 (Safari) or Android 4.1 (Chrome/native webkit browser). It just doesn't play anything. On iOS simulator it does open the login screen for Deezer - which should be needed if you only listen for less than 30seconds and don't need any permissions correct? If I close the popup, I get

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'DZ.login_popup.popup.closed')
(anonymous function) (dz.js, line 38)
```

Also, Deezer keeps complaining about Flash.

```
Flash is not installed or is too old
```

Is this an issue with Deezer JS SDK player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS SDK doesn't have an HTML5 fallback. Only the widget player does. The solution would be to build a custom player playing the 30 seconds mp3s available in the API.

Comment: Bit confusing, since the JS SDK includes the widget player - only as hidden iframe to the page. So basically the difference to normal widget player is the fact that it is hidden? As in above example.

To this, I load the tracks with DZ.player.playTracks([]). It should be able to fallback to HTML5 correct?

http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/example-invisible

Documents this feature.

Comment: Yes the widget is used by the SDK but HTML5 fallback isn't available from there. There are technical issues making that all methods from the SDK couldn't be implemented properly.